# Adding UIBarButtonSystemItem icons to Nav-Toolbar (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, uibarbuttonsystemitem

I have been trying to find a way to add the UIBarButtonSystemItem icon to the toolbar. I have implemented it on my NavBar with the following code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "shareMeme")
```

But when it comes to the toolbar, I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var items: Array<UIBarButtonItem> = []

items.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "selector"))

self.setToolbarItems(items as [AnyObject], animated: true)
self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
```

Comment: The nav bar image is working. It's my toolbar that I would also like images to populate that I can't figure out.

Comment: var actionButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Action, target: self, action: "shareMeme") 
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshButton

should work

Comment: put it in viewdidload

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am looking to address the barButtonItem in my toolbar. Not the navbar

Comment: ah , sorry i misunderstood question because u had code for navigation bar .. u can add items to toolbar with :

var items: Array<UIBarButtonItem> = []

        items.append(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Action, target: self, action: "selector"))
  
        self.setToolbarItems(items as [AnyObject], animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

Comment: i edited my original post .. in it is the code for adding button